# Derived expression for the adjoint of matrix $A$ proof

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis

Let $A$ be a real or complex matrix in a Hilbert space over the complex number, with arbitory inner product $( \cdot , \cdot)$.Using a nonsingular weight matrix, $W$, the inner product can be given by

$$ (u,v) = (Wu)^H (Wv) = u^HW^H W v,$$

where $u,v$ are column vectors and $u^H$ is the complex conjugate transpose. The adjoint of $A$, given by $A^*$, is defined as

$$(Au,v) = (u,A^*v). $$

It is stated that the adjoint can be given by

$$A^* = (W^HW)^{-1} A^H (W^HW).$$

I have had several attempts at getting this, but I can't find how $A^*$ is given in the expression above. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit:

I've started out by expanding out the inner products to give
$$(Au,v) = u^H W^H A^H W v $$
$$(u, A^*v) = u^H W^H A^* W v. $$
Equating these two expressions and rearranging didn't seem to get me any closer. It looks like there needs to be some multiplication/division combination that I'm not seeing.

Edit 2: Corrections

The above should be written as
$$(Au,v) = u^H A^H W^H W v $$
$$(u, A^*v) = u^H W^H W A^* v. $$

Which can be equated together to give
$$ u^H W^H W A^* v = u^H A^H W^H W v,$$
which can cancell further to give
$$ W^H W A^*  =  A^H W^H W.$$
Which can be finally written as
$$ A^*  =  (W^H W)^{-1}A^H W^H W.$$

Comment: So, $(Au, v) = (WAu)^H Wv = u^H A^H W^H Wv$?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I think that's correct now. I've been stuck on that for way too long.

Comment: Fine. Just 2 remarks: 1) in your cancellation of $u^H$ and $v,$ nothing to add since you are looking for *some* $A^*$ satisfying the equality for all $u,v$, and for this it is *sufficient* that $W^H W A^*  =  A^H W^H W$ (actually it is also necessary but you don't need it). 2) $(W^HW)^{-1}$ exists because $W$  (hence also $W^H$) is nonsingular.